# SystemParametersInfo() returns 0 randomly

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm developing an application to randomly change the users wallpaper at a specific time interval. Everything works as expected, except for the occasional error of 0 set by SystemParametersInfo(), which results in the wallpaper being reset to a black screen.

The 0 error is supposed to denote the operation was successful, yet that's obviously not the case. This error does not occur every time a new background is set, but randomly. I've searched this website and many others for possible solutions.. to no avail.

```
void setBackground() {
dirSize = FindMaxFileNum(); //Reads num of .jpg's in the folder.

if(dirSize != -1)
{ 
  srand( (unsigned int)time(NULL));
  bgChoice = rand() % dirSize + 1; 

  //Ensures backgrounds don't repeat. 
  for(int i=0; i<=2; i++) 
  {
    if(lastBackground[i] == bgChoice)
    { bgChoice = rand() % dirSize + 1; }
  }
 //Tracks the last background used. 
 lastBackground[bgCount] = bgChoice; 
 bgCount++; 
 //Resets the counter so we can track the last 3 bg's used. 
 if(bgCount == 2)
 { bgCount = 0; }
}
else 
{ 
  dwLastError = GetLastError();
  ssLastError << "Error: " << dwLastError << "."; 
  MessageBox(NULL, ssLastError.str().c_str(), "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK); 
  ssLastError.str("");
}
ssFilePath.str("");          //Ensures the stringstream is clean. 
ssFilePath << strLocalDirectory << bgChoice << ".jpg";     

if( SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (PVOID)ssFilePath.str().c_str(), 
     SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE) != 0)
{
  // Refresh the desktop - cleaning of PIDL is in the WM_DESTROY message.       
  SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(NULL,CSIDL_DESKTOP,&pidl);
  SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED,SHCNF_IDLIST,pidl,0);
}
else 
{
  dwLastError = GetLastError();
  ssLastError << "Error: " << dwLastError << ".";
  MessageBox(NULL, ssLastError.str().c_str(), "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK); 
  ssLastError.str("");
}
```

}

Comment: *"If the function succeeds, the return value is a nonzero value."* - Why do you assume a return value of 0 indicates success?

Comment: And what is the actual error?

Comment: Well, I feel a little dumb now.. it appears to be working. I found some documentation the other day which noted that SystemParametersInfo() doesn't necessarily return true/false, so it's best to compare it to 0. 

However, I ended up simply doing a boolean comparison and it works fine for now. Thanks anyways! :)

Comment: Also, are you sure there isn't something wrong with the JPG image? Either corruption or for example too large?

Comment: In fact, the error still occurs.. I do know that none of the JPEG's are corrupt, though size might be an issue for some of them. If that were the case, wouldn't the GetLastError() not return the 0 error(operation successful)?

Comment: Comparing against 0 is the same as comparing against false.  Are you sure that the failure is random and doesn't occur with specific images?

Comment: In fact, I have isolated the issue to be a background of larger resolution. Curiously however, when I set this image manually via right-click and "Set as Background" it works.

Is there a reason why Windows can set the background, and my program cannot? Ideally, I would like to support images of virtually any resolution(within reason), without error.